# How does one convert C# List<byte> to NSData?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.forms

I'm working on a Xamarin Forms app (don't ask) and have to write platform-specific code for the iOS solution. I'm primarily an iOS developer, so my C# is lacking in certain areas.

The iOS CBPeripheral.WriteValue call requires an NSData object.

I currently have a C# List data structure. So I need to convert that to NSData in order to write the value.

I've searched on the usual candidates (S.O., etc,) but haven't found a solution to my particular problem.

I'd appreciate any help people can provide.

Comment: `var myNsData = NSData.FromArray(Byte[] array)` ?

Comment: Adding to Franck’s comment you can convert a List<byte> into an byte[] by calling ToArray() on the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if `MyList` is a `List<byte>`

```
var arr = MyList.ToArray<byte>();
var data = NSData.FromArray(arr)
```